# OutOfMemory thread dump without GC history

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, websphere, out-of-memory

Usually generated thread dump after OutOfMemoryError include information about several last Garbage Collector cycles (**GC History** section). But I've got OutOfMemory thread dumps without this information.

```
1STGCHTYPE     GC History  
NULL           
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0SECTION       LOCKS subcomponent dump routine
NULL           ===============================
```

Environment: IBM WebSphere 7.0.0.19

Someone know why this dump don't have this information?
GC didn't start at all?

Comment: Maybe, you could try `jstack [java pid]` for additional info?

Comment: IBM JVM haven't got this utility, but I have information about running threads inside created thread dump. What threads I should investigate?

Comment: Partial answer: To make sure how GC behaves in your case (and for monitoring GC history in general), it may be best to set [-verbose:gc](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.60/diag/tools/gcpd_verbosegc.html) and check `nativestdErr.log` for details, which shows more details.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if your program requested a large enough memory like a large array allocation etc in one go which can't be fulfilled by JVM.

Answer (score 2):

In that case you should look at the `Snap.*.trc` file that the JVM generated together with the dump. It's a binary file, but IBM provides a [tool](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v5r0/topic/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.50/diag/tools/trace_formatter.html) to decode that trace file.

Last time I saw a `javacore` file without GC history, that was because the `OutOfMemoryError` was not triggered by heap (or native memory) starvation, but by excessive garbage collection overhead. That was clearly indicated in the trace file.

Comment: How exactly it should be indicated in the parsed trace file?

Comment: I didn't keep the trace file, so I'm unable to give you the exact message. Anyways, if the JVM decided to generate a dump, then the trace file will mention the reason for that.